# How can the Math behaviour of Java 8 be achieved in Java 17?

Tags: java, c, math, java-8, java-17

We have an growing codebase which also involves doing math calculations on data and store them historically. Now we need to move on and migrate from Java 8 to Java 17 but we noticed the calculation results are different in Java 17! The reason why we try to achieve the same calculation behaviour is because of possible recalculations and historical comparison of data (check if results were calculated correctly in terms of new calculation equals the saved values).

After a lot of research I already know, that Java 8 used optimizations like use more floating precision if available on a system. They use intrinsic functions which modify math operations during runtime for performance improvements. And they rely on fdlibm 5.3, a native c math library. In Java 17 they ported the fdlibm from c to java and use it at least in StrictMath, but still there are intrinsic functions which use native code.

I think the key to achieve what I am trying is to understand how and with which options they compiled the native math code the intrinsic functions use.

I built a JNI library which delegates functions like exp, log, sqrt etc. to native fdlibm. I tried different optimizations like -Ofast, but still the results are not exactly the same.

Maybe the code for operators like division, multiply, plus and minus was also changed?

I ran the tests on the same system so it should be comparable.

**Any ideas how the math behaviour of java 8 can be extracted to use it for legacy calculations in java 17?**

Example of different computation with Math.exp:

```
JVM VERSION: 1.8.0_362 
--- Input number: 0.003978202863827189 
java.lang.Math.exp       : 1.0039861264165226 

JVM VERSION: 17.0.6
--- Input number: 0.003978202863827189 
java.lang.Math.exp       : 1.0039861264165224
```

Example Code for the output above:

```
public class Exp {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.library.path"));
        
        double input = Double.valueOf(args[0]);

        System.out.println("JVM VERSION: " + System.getProperty("java.version"));
        System.out.println("---");
        System.out.println("Input number: " + input);
            
        System.out.println("Math result (java.lang.Math.exp):");
        System.out.println(" -> " + Math.exp(input)); 

    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Are you talking about [JEP 306](https://openjdk.org/jeps/306)?

Comment: how can math calculations have different valid results?

Comment: @SharonBenAsher Older Java version used shortcuts/different calculations (at least on x86) for floating point operations for historic reasons (e.g. it was slower to use strictly conforming calculations on some hardware), and only formally complied with the IEEE-754 standard if you tagged the variables with the `strictfp` keyword. This changed in Java 17 with [JEP-306](https://openjdk.org/jeps/306), the default behaviour is now the same as the strictfp behaviour.

Comment: @SharonBenAsher Given the shortcuts used can result in slightly different values, and if you then consider compound error, the results between the old default behaviour and the strict behaviour can result in larger deviations.

Comment: OP, why can't you accept that the math behaviour changed and move on?

Comment: I added an example, and added a sentence to explain the motivation.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel the example provided is also valid for java 11, means: java 11 also produces a different result than java 8. So there was something introduced even earlier.

Comment: You should be able to "Any ideas how the same math behaviour can be achieved?" You should be able to use `StrictMath` instead of `Math` and get the same results for both jdks.

Comment: I'm going to go out on a limb and guess that in Java 11 (or earlier) they made some changes which affected the non-strict floating point operations, and instead of changing it back (it likely still complied with the spec), they decided to ditch that non-strict behaviour entirely through JEP-306, so they now only have behaviour that complies with the IEEE-754 standard.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel from your description it seems like `Math.exp` and `StrictMath.exp` should be the same for java 17 but different for java 8. That's not what I get though.

Comment: @matt Interesting, I'm not sure if that is a bug or just a deviation allowed by the spec. Given `Math.exp(...)` delegates to `StrictMath.exp(...)`, I guess it should have the same result, but `Math.exp(...)` can be replaced with an intrinsic at runtime, while `StrictMath.exp(...)` cannot.

Comment: @matt yes, it is a good idea to use StrictMath in the future or any other math library which ensures consistency across versions and platforms. 
For now it doesn't solve the problem because StrictMath doesn't deliver the same results like java 8 Math. Check with exp function and number 1.0d

Comment: @MarkRotteveel yes that's also my best guess...
and yes, java.lang.Math delegates to java.lang.StrictMath, BUT because of intrinsic functions the jvm can do something different during runtime to improve performance (e.g. call native code) 
see also this list: 
https://chriswhocodes.com/hotspot_intrinsics_openjdk8.html

Comment: @Nik java 8 uses StrictMath for the Math.exp, I don't get how it can produce a different result, but I tried `a=1.0d;` and `Math.exp(a)` and `StrictMath.exp(a)` They're different. java 17 makes sense because it has the intrisic anotation. It's strange for java 8. So far though all three jdk's I try produce the same strict math results.

Comment: Can not reproduce your problem with `1.0`. On my machine, `StrictMath` produces the same results from Java 8 to Java 21.

Comment: @Holger 1.0 gives different results for Math and StrictMath, that means java 21 StrictMath cannot be used for java 8 Math. The `0.003978202863827189` example gives a different result for java 17 Math and java 8 Math.

Comment: @Holger maybe a misunderstanding: StrictMath produces the same result across jdks, but not the same result like the Math counterpart. Example:

JVM VERSION: 17.0.6
Input number: 1.0
Math result (java.lang.Math.exp):
 -> 2.718281828459045
StrictMath result (java.lang.StrictMath.exp):
 -> 2.7182818284590455

Comment: @matt Java 8 does not necessarily annotate hotspot intrinsic methods. Those methods can replace a pure java method. (And if you change one, but not the other...). Anyway, `Math.pow()` is a hotspot intrinsic since java 6.

Comment: I don’t understand where you’re heading at. If you want consistent results across all versions, use `StrictMath`. In all versions. Of course, it does not (always) produce the same results as `Math`. If it did, what would be the point of having two classes?

Comment: @Holger we have old code that uses java.lang.Math written for java 8. The same code must now run on java 17. The question is how can the same math behavior on java 8 be achieved on java 17 (or even other java versions). java.lang.Math could be only one part of the problem, e.g. I don't know if also math operators like +, -, /, * changed behaviour.
The question how to avoid these problems in the future (e.g. use StrictMath) is a different topic.

Comment: Did you consider building the JDK? Then you should see the options use to build the library.

Comment: @matt I downloaded open-jdk8u and open-jdk17u source repositories. That's how I started my research and I already found out a lot, like the intrinsic functions and usage of fdlibm. But it's a huge code base and I couldn't figure out how the math parts are built yet.

Comment: No, the arithmetic operations did not change their behavior. You tripped over [a single optimization](https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-8132207) and if the application really depends on the last bit of a 64 bit floating point result, there’s a much deeper problem. And if you really consider changing the behavior of the JDK/JVM to be more feasible than fixing your own code, I’d rethink whether your code really “must now run on java 17”.

Comment: Thanks for the hints (arithmetic operations, exp optimization)! Compound errors can amplify the problem. I don't want to build a special version of java 17 - a (JNI?) library with the same behaviour would be sufficient. And of course in the future the code must use something more portable - this is already planned. I'm looking for a possibility to calculate old data with the old behaviour and newer data with the portable/standard behaviour. There are a lot reasons java 17 must be used in the future, e.g. overall performance, long term support/security patches, features to name a few...

Comment: @Nik yes, it is a monster, the ones I look at have pretty good instructions for building the jdk. I would suggest building it. Making sure it produces the results you want. You'll also be able to find the lib's you needs, and the commands used to build them with tools like `find` and `grep`

Comment: You assume that the JDK 8 Math behavior is correct.  That might not be the case.  I'd go for the JDK 17 StrictMath results.

Comment: Writing that hypothetical JNI library still would be more effort than just using `StrictMath`. And why do you think about “performance, long term support/security patches, etc” when you’re going to throw it all away by introducing a new JNI library to your code that will kill the performance and likely introduce bugs and security holes.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because while there is an inconvenient here, there is no _problem_ here, IEEE floating points decimals are explicitly inaccurate, and code that relies on precision in the last few decimals but also uses IEEE floating point decimals is using the wrong datatype entirely: those decimals are guaranteed to almost never be right no matter which version of java (or any other programming language) you use. You don't try to fix Java 17, you should _really_ fix your code.

Comment: I don't assume java 8 Math is "correct". The discussion is not about mathematical correctness. And like I said StrictMath and/or other datatypes is the way to go in the future. I also don't try to "fix" java 17 everything is fine there. 
I'm looking for a possibility to achieve the same outcome in the math computations for legacy code and data there already is. This old stuff will slowly fade away after some years. 
I couldn't figure out how to extract the math behaviour of the jdk source and therefore asked the community

Comment: There is an easy way to keep to the outcome of the legacy code the same. Keep running the legacy code with the legacy Java version. It’s ok, if you don’t want to touch that code (and rather let it fade away). But then, don’t touch the code.

Comment: If you look at the included libraries in java 8 you can find that `liblcms.so` contains math symbols. One of them being `U exp@GLIBC_2.2.5`  There is also the StrictMath exp reference, but I think it is refering to the GLIBC one.

Answer (score 0):

When comparing floating point numbers, you should ALWAYS take the accuracy of the numbers involved into account. That accuracy is almost always much less than the accuracy of the floating point representation. So it should not matter for your results whether the mathematical operations have become a tiny bit more accurate.

Therefore, when "checking if results were calculated correctly", take the accuracy of the results into account.

Comment: You shouldn't be doing floating point calculations in the first place if you need accuracy. Use BigDecimal for that matter. If you want to keep using floating points you have to consider accuracy as this answer states.

Comment: This suggestion isn't wrong, but it's also missing the point. OP quite specifically asked for the "non-strict" x86 behaviour of old JVMs on a current JVM. (I don't think you can get that, but that's besides the point).

Comment: @JoachimSauer This tries to answer the problem that the OP really has, rather than the problem they think they have.

Answer (score 0):

We had a similar problem with Math.exp() when switching from Oracle JDK 8 to Zulu JDK 11.

Solution which worked was replacing Math.exp() with Apache Commons Math library call. Results matched Java 8 (commons-math3-3.4.1).

Not sure about performance - it was not that critical in our case.